# I am trying to reproduce this CFD simulation with a car-shaped obstacle but it is not turning out how I'd like to

Tags: matlab, octave

Here's what I am trying to reproduce : [CFD simulation - Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixu0k.png)

Here's what I get using my code : [My stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOx4F.png)

The equations I used initially were the Euler ones from [the NASA website](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/eulereqs.html) and I added the time variable to the 2 momentum equations.

I also followed [theses two videos to help with discretization (11 and 12)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjfxA3qq2Lg)

I need to mention that I am truly a beginner in CFD and coding in general so my experience with these things is extremely limited.

Here's my code, I've been writing it on Octave but I realized Matlab itself is much faster for executing it :

```
clear all;

nx = 80; ny = 60;
nt = 20; nit = 20; dt = 0.01;
vis = 0; rho = 1.225;

dx = 5/(nx-1); dy = 2/(ny-1);
x = 0:dx:5; y = 0:dy:2;
u = zeros(nx,ny);
v = zeros(nx,ny);
p = zeros(nx,ny);

cmap = flipud(jet(256));

%u([1,2], 1) = 0;
%v([1,2], 1) = 0;
%p(:, 2) = 0;

[y,x] = meshgrid(y,x);
u(:, :) = 0.1;

for it = 1:nt+1

  % constant flow from the left wall
  u(1, :) = 0.1;

  for i = 2:nx-1
    for j = 2:ny-1
      b(i,j) = rho*( (u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,j))/2/dx + (v(i,j+1)-v(i,j-1))/2/dy )/dt + rho*(((u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,j))/2/dx).^2 + 2*(u(i,j+1)-u(i,j-1))/2/dy*(v(i+1,j)-v(i,j-1))/2/dx) + ( (v(i,j+1)-v(i,j-1))/2/dy ).^2;
    end
  end

  b(nx,:) = 0; b(:,ny) = 0;       % add row and column 20 = 0 for pcolor to 
 match (19 v 20)

  for iit = 1:nit+1
    pn = p;
    for i = 2:nx-1
      for j = 2:ny-1
        p(i,j) = ((pn(i+1,j) + pn(i-1,j))*dy^2 + (pn(i,j+1)+pn(i,j-1))*dx^2 - b(i,j)*dx^2*dy^2) / (dx^2+dy^2) / 2;
      end
    end
    p(1,:) = p(2,:);  p(nx,:) = p(nx-1,:);
    p(:,1) = p(:,2);  p(:,ny) = p(:,ny-1);
  end

  un = u; vn = v;
  for i = 2:nx-1
    for j = 2:ny-1
      u(i,j) = un(i,j) - un(i,j)*dt/dx*(un(i,j) - un(i-1,j)) - vn(i,j)*dt/dy*(un(i,j)-un(i,j-1)) - 1/rho*(p(i+1,j)-p(i-1,j))*dt/2/dx + vis*dt/dx^2*(un(i+1,j)-2*un(i,j)+un(i-1,j)) + vis*dt/dy^2*(un(i,j+1)-2*un(i,j)+un(i,j-1));

      v(i,j) = vn(i,j) - un(i,j)*dt/dx*(vn(i,j) - vn(i-1,j)) - vn(i,j)*dt/dy*(vn(i,j)-vn(i,j-1)) - 1/rho*(p(i,j+1)-p(i,j-1))*dt/2/dy + vis*dt/dx^2*(vn(i+1,j)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i-1,j)) + vis*dt/dy^2*(vn(i,j+1)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i,j-1));
      end
    end
    u(1,:) = 0;  u(nx,:) = 0;  u(:,1) = 0;  u(:,ny) = 0;
    v(1,:) = 0;  v(nx,:) = 0;  v(:,1) = 0;  v(:,ny) = 0;  % set borders to 0


  % car front
  for c = 1:8
    for d = 1:10
      u(c+11, d+4) = 0;
      v(c+11, d+4) = 0;
    end
  end

  % car body
  for c = 1:11
    for d = 1:17
      u(c+19, d+4) = 0;
      v(c+19, d+4) = 0;
    end
  end

  % car rear
  for c = 1:8
    for d = 1:10
      u(c+30, d+4) = 0;
      v(c+30, d+4) = 0;
    end
  end

end

colormap (cmap);
pcolor(x,y,b);
shading interp;
hold on;
quiver (x, y, u, v, 'color', [0 0 0]);
```

Comment: Euler equations are applicable only for inviscid flows. The result that you showed in the first link have wake vortices which implies there is viscosity in it. I am afraid that you are solving the wrong governing equations. It is unlikely that it is just an error in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The incompressible Navier-Stokes equations (similar to the Euler equations but with diffusion) are the typical choice for these types of simulations. In your simulation case it is typical to have a 5-20 times longer zone after the car due to the flow being more complex there (recirculation zone). If you don't wish to write your own code you might consider using a [Matlab CFD toolbox](http://www.featool.com/matlab-cfd-toolbox) and follow the [tutorial for flow over a cylinder](http://www.featool.com/doc/tutorials.html#ex_ns1) (while substituting the cylinder for your car geometry). Lastly, if the built-in solver is too slow you can also use the OpenFOAM CFD solver integration to speed up the simulation.